# My complex integral cancels at the end; how can I modify the integrand to prevent this?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^a}{x^2 + b^2}$$

for $-1< a < 1$ and b>0 -- these constraints help with estimating the integral on the big circle and small circle of a keyhole contour that I chose to use.

But in the end, the remaining two integrals over the two straight lines, above and below $R^+$, cancel each other out.

EDIT: as per the comments below, the integrals don't cancel, so I have my final answer as $$\frac {\pi b^{a-1}2i[sin(\frac{\pi a}{2})]}{1-e^{ia2 \pi}},$$

which is still a complex number, unfortunately.  The solution that I compared my work to has the answer of

$$\frac {\pi b^{a-1}}{2cos(\frac{\pi a}{2})},$$, and it integrated on a simpler, upper semi-circle, while avoiding the branch point at 0.

I am pretty sure my computations over the two straight lines are correct, but I will try again tomorrow, as it is really late here :-(

If the above two solutions are, by inspection, **equivalent**, please let me know :-)

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure that they cancel? Remember that $x^a = \exp(a\log x)$, and the argument of $x$ will be different "above" and "below" the positive real axis.

Comment: Hi @mrf, the integral from "below" picks up a factor of $e^{ia2\pi}$ = $1^a$ = 1, so that the integrand is still the same as the integrand for the integral "above" the positive real axis (similar situation with the $x^2$, with it picking up a factor of $e^{i4\pi}$ = 1.  Unless I have my calculations wrong...

Comment: $\exp(ia2\pi) = \cos(2\pi a) + i\sin(2\pi a)$ which is not $1$ (unless $a$ is an integer; in your case $a=0$)

Comment: Ok, thanks @mrf.  My final answer is different from the solution that I just compared my work to -- it uses simply an upper semi-circle and avoids the branch point at 0.  But I'm pretty sure that my work on a keyhole contour is all correct.  I just picked up an extra residue term.  Do you think the choice of contour makes a difference?

Comment: Every correctly chosen contour should lead to the same result in the end :)

Comment: Hi @tired, yes I agree :(  I've edited my question to show my final answer, and how it compares to the answer in the solution.  Feel free to comment on it, if you want.  Thanks for your time,

Comment: Have you calculated the residues by hand or with the help of a CAS?

Comment: Hi @tired -- all computations, including verifying the solution's approach, were by hand.  I then tried using wolfram, and it said "computation time exceeded".

Comment: Ok, because Mathematica has a distinct standard branch which is often not useful

Comment: Alternately, let $x=bt$ and $u=\dfrac1{t^2+1}$ , then recognize the expression of the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the new integral, and use Euler's [reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) to arrive at the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contour encloses the two poles at $\pm i b$, so we find

$$(1 - e^{2\pi i a})\int_0^\infty \frac{x^a}{x^2+b^2}\,dx = 2\pi i \Biggl(\operatorname{Res}\biggl(\frac{z^a}{z^2+b^2}; ib\biggr) + \operatorname{Res}\biggl(\frac{z^a}{z^2+b^2}; -ib\biggr)\Biggr).$$

For the residues, we have

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Res}\biggl(\frac{z^a}{z^2+b^2}; ib\biggr) &= \frac{(ib)^a}{2ib} = b^{a-1}\frac{1}{2i}e^{\pi ia/2},\\
\operatorname{Res}\biggl(\frac{z^a}{z^2+b^2}; -ib\biggr) &= \frac{(-ib)^a}{-2ib} = -b^{a-1}\frac{1}{2i}e^{3\pi ia/2},
\end{align}

since with the chosen branch of $w\mapsto w^a$ we have $(-i)^a = e^{3\pi ia/2}$ - with the branch cut on the positive real half-axis, we chose the branch with $0 < \arg z < 2\pi$, so $-i = e^{3\pi i/2}$. The residue sum is hence

$$\frac{b^{a-1}}{2i}e^{\pi i a/2}(1 - e^{\pi ia})$$

and

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^a}{x^2+b^2}\,dx = \frac{\pi b^{a-1}e^{\pi i a/2}(1 - e^{\pi i a})}{1-e^{2\pi ia}} = \frac{\pi b^{a-1} e^{\pi i a/2}}{1+e^{\pi i a}} = \frac{\pi b^{a-1}}{e^{-\pi ia/2} + e^{\pi i a/2}} = \frac{\pi b^{a-1}}{2\cos \frac{\pi a}{2}}.$$

I suspect that you chose the wrong branch to compute $(-i)^a$ in the residue at $-ib$ and got the value

$$-\frac{b^{a-1}}{2i} e^{-\pi i a/2}$$

there, which gives a sum of

$$b^{a-1} \frac{e^{\pi i a/2} - e^{-\pi ia/2}}{2i} = b^{a-1}\sin \frac{\pi a}{2}$$

and thus leads precisely to your erroneous result.

Comment: Hi @DanielFischer, thank you for this amazing answer.  I think you are absolutely right.  I will try again after I get some sleep.  Thanks so much for your time.  Have a great night! :-)

Comment: Hi @DanielFischer, in your string of equalities, how do you arrive at the second equality?  I am having some trouble simplifying $\frac{1-e^{ i \pi a} }{ 1-e^{2\pi a}}$

Comment: Hi @DanielFischer, I have figured it out --  thanks again for your help :-)